# Disable Http Request Tracking from Serilog appsettings.json

Tags: azure, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights, serilog

I'm working on .netcore6 web app on Azure, using Serilog with Serilog AzureInsights Sink for the core debugging mechanism. I want to disable the `HttpRequest` logging sent to `Azure Insights` by default. I checked the doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6 and apparently there is a config `EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule` that would allow me to do just that.

The issue here is I'm not able to configure it from `appsettings.json`, where would be the best place to put it?

Below is my current config for reference:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning"          
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString" : "InstrumentationKey=ff394818-38fa-4239-8cb4-3380d6812e4d;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-1.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/", 
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
          "EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule": false
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  }
```

and `Program.cs` for reference:

```
    public class Program {

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
   
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateBootstrapLogger();
            
            try {
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred during bootstrapping");
            } finally {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
                    config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

                    var configuration = config.Build();
                })

                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                        webBuilder.UseKestrel()
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .UseSerilog(
                    (hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                    .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                 );

    }
```

Comment: Please share your `Program.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to configure the Telemetry Modules:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new 
    ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
    {
        EnableDependencyTrackingTelemetryModule = false,
        EnableRequestTrackingTelemetryModule = false,
    });
```